# Solving for a matrix times the reciprocal of a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

I am trying to solve this equation for $x$:

$$M \cdot (1/x) = x$$

where $M$ is a *non-negative*, real-valued invertible $n x n$ matrix, and $x$ is a non-zero $n \times 1$ vector. The notation $1/x$ just denotes the element-wise reciprocal of $x$:

$$ 1/x = (1/x_1,1/x_2,...1/x_n)'$$

Is there a closed form solution to this equation? It seems so simple that I feel there must be, but I am stuck.

If it's not possible to give a closed form solution, is it at least possible to show that there must be some solution that is real and strictly positive?  In other words, that there is at least one solution, $x^*=(x_1^*,...,x_n^*)$, where  $x_i^*$ is real, and $x_i^*>0 \hspace{.2cm}\forall i \hspace{.2cm}$?

**EDIT**: To clarify, $M$ is a non-negative matrix.

Thanks!

Comment: $(x_1, x_2,\cdots, x_n) \to (\frac 1{x_1},\frac 1{x_2},\cdots, \frac 1{x_n})$ is not a linear transformation.  There will not be a matrix representation of this function.

Comment: That's what I imagine, but can I get an equation for this, even if not in matrix notation? And moreover, can I show that this solution is strictly positive?

Comment: If $M=-I$ there is no real vector, positive or negative, solving this. There are complex vectors.

Comment: See my edit -- M is non-negative.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the case $2 \times 2$. Given an invertible matrix
$$M = \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
c & d\\
\end{array}\right],$$
we want to find a vector $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that
$$M = \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
c & d\\
\end{array}\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
\frac{1}{x}\\
\frac{1}{y}\\
\end{array}\right] = 
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y\\
\end{array}\right].$$

This gives the system 
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
\frac{a}{x} + \frac{b}{y} = x\\
\frac{c}{x} + \frac{d}{y} = y\\
\end{array}\right.$$
which can not have real solutions for some choices of the coefficients $a,b,c,d$. For example, consider $a,b,d < 0$ and $c = 0$.

If you are concerned about higher dimensions, it's still possible to come up with counterexamples, as showed in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So you bring up a good point. The matrix $M$ is actually the inverse of a non-negative matrix. I didn't think this mattered originally, but apparently this feature is what is ensuring that there is a non-negative solution. But I can't find any properties of the inverse of a non-negative matrix that makes this problem any easier....